# flexbox element over image background color css

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, background-color

I've been trying to convert my site to flexbox, and I've run into a snag. One element I was able to pull off using floats, I now can't since floats don't work when using flexbox.

Basically I've got an image that has something pop over it when you hover on it. This I have working, but the background color does not appear over the image. I'm trying to figure out how to get it to appear over the image, i've tried giving the element a really high z-index and a bunch of other stuff, and i'm coming up empty handed. I wish I could use a css background image instead of a html image but I can't get those to scale and maintain perspective in css (has to stay the size of the background image, not the elements contents)

here's my example code:

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dldoc p {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.docwrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dldoc {
  margin: .5em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 30vw;
  height: 55vw;
}

.dldoc p {
  height: 30vh;
  background: #f0f;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.dldoc strong {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dldoc em,
.dldoc p {
  font-size: 4.5vw;
}

.dldoc:hover>p {
  margin-top: -40vw;
}

.dlmap {
  padding: 0;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.dlmap:hover,
.dlmap:active {
  top;
}

.dldoc img {
  z-index: 100;
  height: 55vw;
}

.dlmap img,
.dldoc img {
  width: 100%;
}

.dlmap strong {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #bbb;
  background: #233;
}

.dlmap a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #233;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7d1;
  width: 100%;
}

.dlmap a:hover {
  background: #7d1;
  color: #233;
}
```

```html
<div class="docwrapper">
  <a href="#" class="dldoc" id="resumedl"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eHu2WOp.png" alt="">
    <p><strong>download</strong><br>test1<br>PDF<br><br><em>test text</em></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="dldoc" id="foliodl"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eHu2WOp.png" alt="">
    <p><strong>download</strong><br>test2<br>ZIP<br><br><em>test text</em></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually a common overlay question and has been asked before. The key is to use absolute positioning on the overlay and relative positioning on the parent.

Comment: > This is actually a common overlay question and has been asked before. The key is to use absolute positioning on the overlay and relative positioning on the parent. – hungerstar


That fixed it! completely forgot you had to put a relative in the parent to get absolute to work like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common overlay question and has been asked before. The key is to use absolute positioning for the overlay and relative positioning on the parent. Shove it out of view and animate it in, usually with `top`.

The main point of using relative positioning on the parent is to contain the absolute positioned element. Absolute positioned elements will position themselves relative to the nearest positioned ancestor element, if there are none, that will be the browser/viewport window. Other than that you can use percentage values for `top` top move the overlay in/out of view and to set the height/width of overlay.

I've marked all the modifications/additions to the CSS with `/**/`.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dldoc p {
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.docwrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.dldoc {
  position: relative; /**/
  margin: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 30vw;
  height: 55vw;
}

.dldoc p {
  position: absolute; /**/
  top: 100%; /**/
  margin: 0; /**/
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff00ff;
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  /* z-index: 10000 */
}

.dldoc strong {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dldoc em,
.dldoc p {
  font-size: 4.5vw;
}

.dldoc:hover>p {
  top: 0; /**/
}

.dlmap {
  padding: 0;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1em
}

.dlmap:hover,
.dlmap:active {
  top
}

.dldoc img {
  z-index: 100;
  height: 55vw
}

.dlmap img,
.dldoc img {
  width: 100%
}

.dlmap strong {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #bbb;
  background: #233
}

.dlmap a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #233;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #7d1;
  width: 100%
}

.dlmap a:hover {
  background: #7d1;
  color: #233
}
```

```html
<div class="docwrapper">
  <a href="#" class="dldoc" id="resumedl"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eHu2WOp.png">
    <p><strong>download</strong><br/>test1<br/>PDF<br/><br/><em>test text</em></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="dldoc" id="foliodl"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eHu2WOp.png">
    <p><strong>download</strong><br/>test2<br/>ZIP<br/><br/><em>test text</em></p>
  </a>
</div>
```